# when loading a page content through ajax post and codeigniter load functions, some jquery functions are in the head section cannot be called

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I know My question Title is not perfectly describe my question extremely sorry about that. I don't know how to tell this as a summery. anyway this is my question.

I am making a admin panel to change some of the content in my web page. this scenario is for change slideshow images.

ok then after someone logged into my page I am loading three pages. like this.

```
$this->load->view('admin/header');
$this->load->view('admin/menu');
$this->load->view('admin/table_and_editor_holder');
```

all the page contents I have mentioned below. so basic path is like this. once someone logged he can click the button [slide manage] to load the images and details of already inserted slides. these are getting from a database. so once he clicked the menu button. this jquery function is executing.

```
$('.menu-item > a').on('click', function() {...})
```

this function simply getting a html page. filled with previous slide details. this is the controller function handle the menu request.

```
function slider_edit_delete() {
    $sdata['slide_imgs'] = $this->admin_basic_curd->get_all_items('sider_images');
    $slide_manager = $this->load->view('admin/slider_manager', $sdata, TRUE);
    echo $slide_manager;
}
```

so previous jquery function is then appending this page content to a div like this.

```
$('#table_container').html(data);
```

so inside this page content I have a buttons call edit for each slide already inserted. so by clicking on of this button I can edit that slide image or some test content of it. that button is like this.

```
<a class="onclick_post_by_a" href="<?php echo base_url() . 'adm_edit_this_slide/' . $sl->id; ?>">
    <button class="btn btn-info"> Edit </button>
</a>
```

**so by clicking this button must execute this function in the header section and this function must add a html form (in a separate page) to the #editor-form-container div as previously**

```
$('.onclick_post_by_a').on('click', function() {...})
```

**but the problem is once I click the edit button it couldn't find this function. so it is opening the content as a separate page**

**How can I make this to work? Thank you** 
the header page contains all the css and js file links. and some jquery functions. like this.

```
    <script>
           $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.menu-item > a').on('click', function() {
                var url = $(this).attr('href');
                var pdata = "";
                var rdata = posting_url(url, pdata);
                rdata.success(function(data) {
                    $('#table_container').html(data);
                });
                return false;
            });
            $('#editor-form-container').css({
                display: "none"
            });
            function posting_url(url, pdata) {
                return $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    data: pdata
                });
            }
            $('.onclick_post_by_a').on('click', function() {
                var url = $(this).attr('href');
                var pdata = "";
                var rdata = posting_url(url, pdata);
                rdata.success(function(data) {
                    $('#editor-form-container').css({
                        display: "block"
                    });
                    $('#editor-form-container').html(data);
                });
                return false;
            });

            $('.post_with_image').on('submit', (function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var formData = new FormData(this);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: $(this).attr('action'),
                    data: formData,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log("success");
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error: function(data) {
                        console.log("error");
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });
            }));
        });
        </script> 
    </head>
```

then I have load menu page. it is like this.

```
<div class="admin-navi">
    <div class="menu-item">
        Home
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url() . 'adm_slide_manage'; ?>"> Side Manage </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

table_and_editor_holder.php page. it is like this.

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
    <div id="table_container" class="col-lg-8">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="editor-form-container" class="col-lg-6">
</div>
```

Comment: Wasn't this possible to narrow down the question a little bit?

Comment: hmm. simply what I need to do is include separate php file (B) that has some dynamic html content in to a div tag of a another html page (A). so this done by a jquery function in the head section of the (A) page. 

so after this done inside of the (B) page content by a button click I need to execute a jquery function in page(A)'s header. but this function cannot execute. because it saying undefined.

Comment: @AfghanWiz - please check this question. I make the scenario simple. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26277999/a-jquery-function-appended-html-content-to-a-div-element-but-that-html-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamically created element does not respond to direct call to events like below -

```
$('.onclick_post_by_a').on('click', function() {...})
```

So you have to write like this

```
$(document).on('click', '.onclick_post_by_a', function() {...})
```

Just try it out.

Comment: Yes! Thank You. I created another question by simplifying this scenario. and got the same answer. 

Thank you for giving me your valuable time