# a jquery function appended html content to a div element. but that html elements cannot access a jquery function in the head section

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Previously I put my question in stackoverflow with all details. but I couldn't get any help. so now I am making my scenario simple and put my question again here.

I have three php files.

```
index.php
request.php
test.php
```

This is the Index.php file. In this file header I have two simple jquery functions. one function is loading separate php file in to the #editor-form-container div tag. other function is just giving an alert when it called.

In the body of this page I have a div tag having the text "click me for button" and this div is calling the posting_url() function once it clicked and that function is loading external php file as describe before.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            function posting_url() {
                var url = 'request.php';
                var pdata = "";
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    data: pdata,
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#editor-form-container').html(data);
                    }
                });
            }
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.click_me_for_alert').on('click', function() {
                    alert("You clicked a button.");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        // put your code here
        ?>
        <div onclick="posting_url()">
            Click me for button
        </div>
        <div id="editor-form-container">
            <button class="click_me_for_alert">
                Iam a default button
            </button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is the request.php file. it is just requiring the test.php file

```
<?php.
require_once 'teset.php';
?>.
```

then in the test.php file. I have a simple button. like this.

```
<button class="click_me_for_alert">
    Iam a appended button
</button>
```

Before I click the div that having the text "Click me for button" if I click the Iam a default button. then it gives me the alert.

But the problem is after I click the div tag "Click me for button" and after the Iam a appended button appears if I click that button it is not giving me that alert. no console errors.

why this is happening?

Comment: Is your html being rendered correctly? I am no expert on php, but what i read about require_once is that it does not execute code, it more like "makes it avaiable for function calls", try changing it to require 'test.php' instead (observer in your code snippet you have written tesEt.php NOT test.php) If i copy paste the expected HTML into a fiddle it works just fine: http://fiddle.jshell.net/c3v10rp9/

Comment: I tried this. 

$("#editor-form-container").on('click', '.click_me_for_alert', function() {
                alert("this is me");
            });
But not working. same problem. nothing in console

Comment: Yes for sure. same class. 
when trying this way 
$("#editor-form-container").on('click', '.click_me_for_alert' function() {
                alert("this is me");
            });
it gives a console error.

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
 

"#editor-form-container").on('click', '.click_me_for_alert' function() {

Comment: Ok got it. this worked. 

 $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#editor-form-container").on('click', '.click_me_for_alert', function() {
                    alert("this");
                });
            });

Thank You for your effort. can you put this as a answer then I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamically created elements use delegated event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#editor-form-container").on('click', '.click_me_for_alert', function()
    {
        alert("You clicked a button.");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. for giving your time for this. :)

Comment: You're welcome. This missed comma was inadvertence from me :)

Answer (score 0):

[**Mutation-Observers**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) is the one way to handle the issue in hand,
Add the following code after document.ready function of your code:

```
<script>
var target = $( "#editor-form-container" );
// Create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function( mutations ) {
   mutations.forEach(function( mutation ) {
   var newNodes = mutation.addedNodes; // DOM NodeList
if( newNodes !== null ) { // If there are new nodes added

    $('.click_me_for_alert').on('click', function() {
                alert("You clicked a button.");
            });  }
   });    
});

// Configuration of the observer:
var config = { 
attributes: true, 
childList: true, 
characterData: true 
};

// Pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);
</script>
```

Put this code just before closing body tag. [List of browsers that support mutation observers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver)

Although this will work fine but still **SUGGESTION BY @REGENT IS MUCH PREFERABLE WAY TO DO IT**.

Comment: not me. anyway thank you for trying to help me. Regent answer solved the problem

Comment: @Yasitha: Anytime, well if you get time do try my solution too. Its always fun to be able to solve a problem in multiple ways.

Comment: Yeh did tried it. but this is not giving the alert. as well as there is no console errors.